# Mosquitto Last Will when unplugging broker power

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using the Last Will and Testament feature of MQTT so that I can easily detect when a client has gone down. It's very handy because that way, I don't display outdated information when the node is actually down, unable to update them.

I also activated the persistence in the disk, so that when the broker starts, we don't need to "wait" for states to be filled, rather we immediately start from the latest info we had last time power was on.

But the problem is when I **cut the power** in the house.
The client and the broker will be stopped at the same time. So the **LWT mechanism cannot be triggered, because broker's death is instantaneous**. We cannot write "offline" into the topic.

When the power gets back, the **broker will wrongly assumes** that my client is online, although it is not true.

The LWT feature makes things very robust for client side problems.
But what should I do to make the system more robust to power cuts on broker side?

- Should I disable the persistent storage in the broker? (No "online" state stored in disk)
  => But with the drawback that I'll start with everything being empty?
- Should I make the broker publish on all LWT topics the "offline" value upon each startup, before any client can connect?
  => This implies forbidding any client to be able to connect to it before all LWT topics are updated to an initial "offline" state.

Or is there an easier/cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

**What should I do to make the system more robust to power cuts on broker side?**
You can install UPS for server to make the system more robust to power cuts on broker side. Nowadays Smart-UPS are available that inform you when mainline power is lost. You can conduct graceful shutdown when you detect power loss.

**Should I disable the persistent storage in the broker? (No "online" state stored in disk) => But with the drawback that I'll start with everything being empty?**
I personally prefer to disable the persistent storage in the broker. In my system (client/server architecture), I make client query the server (note-server is different from broker) for latest state and its the server's responsibility to get back the client to desired state.
I don't live things on chance my depending the broker to get the client to desired state.
The downside of this approach is more latency/delay in startup and additional programming/maintenance haste.

**Should I make the broker publish on all LWT topics the "offline" value upon each startup, before any client can connect? => This implies forbidding any client to be able to connect to it before all LWT topics are updated to an initial "offline" state.**
I couldn't get what you are trying to convey. Can you elaborate on the same.
From the limited understanding to your question I can state that you can't (should not) make broker do anything else then maintaining proper MQTT connection stream. Everything else should be handled by your server (software). This way you have maximum control and deterministic/predictable behavior.

Comment: UPS: It would be a solution but I'm only looking for software solutions. :)
By server, I mean the MQTT server (broker) (the passive part sending SYN/ACK).
By client, I mean the MQTT client (the active part sending SYN).

Comment: I'm suddenly thinking of disabling the "retain" flag only for Last Will & Testament topics. That way it would not be stored whereas other topics get stored (I need to check that).

Comment: Disabling retain flag is the right way to do. You should maintain states in your software and in case of disturbance you should update the state from node.